# Push Array in Array with split function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, split, push

I'm wondering why I'm having the result and undefined at the same time...

```
var arrayFrases = [];
var numeroCasos;
var arrayFrasesCambiadas = [];


    function alCargar(){
        numeroCasos = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos casos desea probar"));       
        document.write("<h2>Casos:</h2>");

    for(var i=0;i<numeroCasos;i++){

        document.write((i +1) + '<input id="caso'+ (i +1) +'" name="nCasos" type="text"> <br>');
        }       
        document.write('<button onclick="voltear()">Voltear</button><br>');
    }

    function voltear(){
        document.write("<h2>Casos al revés: </h2>");
        for(var i=0;i<numeroCasos;i++){ 
            arrayFrases.push(document.getElementById("caso"+(i+1)).value);
            var cadenaSeparada=[];                  
            cadenaSeparada.push(arrayFrases[i].split(" "));
            alert(cadenaSeparada[0]);
            alert(cadenaSeparada[1]);
            document.write("Caso # "+ (i+1) + '<label id="cambiarCaso'+ (i +1) + '" name="cambiarCasos" type="text">' +  cadenaSeparada[i] + '</label><br>');

             }

        }
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="alCargar()">Ejercicio 1</button>
```

Why I'm having undefined ... how can i solve this...

Sorry, for the explain I speak spanish ajajaj first time I ask anything and it drives me crazy all the alarms... mostly code, not properly code... etc...

Comment: please post your whole code. Thanks

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: What is `undefined` in the above code?

Comment: @void I don't know, where is getting that, because I'm pushing phrases and split them in the space " " ...

Comment: Okay what is that which you are expecting to happen but does not happen?

Comment: @void in the label needs to set the first phrase separated with "," but this program is setting the second label with undefined... and that is not the second phrase... label 1  hola, como, estas.... label 2, undefined... even when the prase [1] being something else

Comment: `numeroCasos` is just a String. Why are you looping through it? Also dont use `document.write()` it replaces the `HTML` of the whole page, Use `element.innerHTML` instead.

Comment: @void numeroCasos = parseInt(prompt)... the user needs to decide how many scenarios are... those are input text... then thos input text are in a array... well I need to separe thos in another array with ","...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the part of code that is causing you the `undefined` problem:

```
cadenaSeparada[i]
```

`I` is the index of `numeroCasos` not an index of `cadenaSeparada`.

So a working solution would be:

```
for (var j = 0; j < cadenaSeparada.length; j++) {
  //MOSTRAR CADENA EN LABEL DE CASOS
  document.write("Caso # " + (i + 1) + '<label id="cambiarCaso' + (i + 1) + '" name="cambiarCasos" type="text">' + cadenaSeparada[j] + '</label><br>');
}
```

I've made a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/r7tpjpIdKlEkBpujPNyC?p=preview